# How to send data to a detail vc from callOutAccessoryControlTapped: method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to pass some data from a table vc to a detail vc using the code below that works fine.

What I'm trying to do is to also send this data from a map `callOutAccessoryControlTapped:` method but I am unsure how to send the data that way.

How would I send
  `detailViewController.descriptionTextViewString = [[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"short_description"];`
using the
     `callOutAccessoryControlTapped`: method?

The `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` is unrecognized from within the map `callOutAccessoryControlTapped:` method.

Here's my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    ScrollView_ExampleViewController *detailViewController = [[ScrollView_ExampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.latStr = [[[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"address"] objectForKey:@"lat"];
    detailViewController.lngStr = [[[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"address"] objectForKey:@"lng"];

    detailViewController.addressStr = [[[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"address"] objectForKey:@"address"];
    detailViewController.titleStr = [[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

    detailViewController.mainImageUrl = [[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"];

    detailViewController.listingId = [[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];

    detailViewController.descriptionTextViewString = [[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"short_description"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Here's my map annotation `calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)pin calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    ScrollView_ExampleViewController *detailViewController = [[ScrollView_ExampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScrollView_ExampleViewController" bundle:nil];

    MyAnnotation *theAnnotation = (MyAnnotation *) pin.annotation;

    detailViewController.titleStr = theAnnotation.title;
    detailViewController.addressStr = theAnnotation.subtitle;
    //   detailViewController.latStr = theAnnotation.latString;
    // detailViewController.lngStr = theAnnotation.lngString;

    //  detailViewController.url = theAnnotation.theUrl;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to get the tableView's selected index:

`NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];`

Comment: thanks! I added that to the calloutAccessoryControlTapped: method, but how do I change it so that the indexPath.row is recognized in:    detailViewController.descriptionTextViewString = [[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"short_description"];

Comment: should I change indexPath.row to selectedIndexPath?

Comment: If you want to set `detailViewController.descriptionTextViewString` in the calloutAccessoryControlTapped, then yes, you have to use the selectedIndexPath as follows:

`detailViewController.descriptionTextViewString = [[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"short_description"];`

Comment: It seemed to have worked, the only problem now is that it's the same record (or row) every time